# 14.04 - Connects to wireless network but can't transmit data

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

When my computer first boots up I the internet works fine for about 30 seconds. In those thirty seconds it has a harder time loading data and after 30 seconds can no longer transmit data. It still remains connected though. I have also had this same problem with multiple wireless adapters.

When I ping the host (192.168.1.1) I get this output:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.133 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.133 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.133 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.133 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Here are outputs for...

iwconfig

```
wlan1     IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"EEE"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: 94:10:3E:02:65:91   
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=86/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:6d:04:65:3f:e2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.133  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:556 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:556 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:91777 (91.7 KB)  TX bytes:91777 (91.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9a:52:d3:99:6e:92  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:e9:84:09:4e:ec  
          inet addr:192.168.1.187  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c6e9:84ff:fe09:4eec/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:85:c202:9f32:c6e9:84ff:fe09:4eec/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:85:c202:9f32:fcd1:c449:5d45:7b24/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1100 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:554 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:289511 (289.5 KB)  TX bytes:78165 (78.1 KB)
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Comment: You *are* connected via eth0 according to `ifconfig -a`. Are you not able to ping nevertheless or is your question why it does not work via wifi? And please show the output of `route -n` too. Is 192.168.1.1 your router?

Comment: I cannot ping to any wireless networks. Wired ones work just fine. And I added the output you asked for.

Comment: Just disable your wired network.

Comment: I'm not connected to a wired network. There's no cable ethernet cable pluged in to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my `/etc/network/interfaces` file to the 14.04 default. I had tinkered with it in the past and its likely that something I either added or removed was causing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I had this problem 20 minutes ago. What I did to fix it may not work for you, but it did work for me.

1: turn off hardware switch,
2: turn on hardware switch,
3: put the laptop in sleep mode,
4: press any key on the keyboard to wake up the laptop from sleep mode,
5: select the option in the Wireless drop-down menu "Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network...",
6: select your desired Wi-Fi network in the drop-down menu and connect.

(note: in step 5, you may not have to select "Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network..." if you already see your network name)

Again, it may not work for you, but it did for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me. But thanks for your help.